# CS50x Blur - feedback

Tags: c, memory, cs50

I'm currently seeking feedback on my code. I'm currently attempting to blur an image provided by the course I'm currently taking. 
I have been able to iterate through each independent pixel and if it is out of bound, skips it and continues with second and so forth iterations. 
I'm currently seeking guidance on what I'm doing wrong in order to proceed fixing it.

You will also find an attachment of the Terminal with the errors I continue to receive. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcOfW.png)

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int redAvg = 0, greenAvg = 0, blueAvg = 0, count = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int pl = i - 1; pl <= i + 1; pl++)
            {
                for (int pw = i - 1; pw <= j + 1; pw++)
                {
                    redAvg += image[i][j].rgbtRed;
                    blueAvg += image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                    greenAvg += image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                    count++;

                    if (pl < 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (pw < 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            redAvg /= count;
            blueAvg /= count;
            greenAvg /= count;

            if (redAvg > 255)
            {
                redAvg = 255;
            }
            if (blueAvg > 255)
            {
                blueAvg = 255;
            }
            if (greenAvg > 255)
            {
                greenAvg = 255;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `redAvg += image[i][j].rgbtRed;` Should that be `redAvg += image[pl][pw].rgbtRed;`? With that, you need to check that the indexes are not out of bounds.

Comment: yes, thanks @JohnnyMopp. small details like these make the difference.....

Comment: You must reset the count and the averages between the outer 2 loops and the inner 2 loops. Also, the averages *won't* be `> 255`.

Comment: Didn't we answer this exact same question last week?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong indexes in the loop and not resetting the variables each iteration.

```
for( int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        // Reset for current pixel
        redAvg = blueAvg = greenAvg = 0;
        count = 0;
        for (int pl = i - 1; pl <= i + 1; pl++) {
            for (int pw = j - 1; pw <= j + 1; pw++) {
                // Ensure not out of bounds
                if (pl >= 0 && pl < height && pw >= 0 && pw < width) {
                    redAvg += image[pl][pw].rgbtRed;
                    blueAvg += image[pl][pw].rgbtGreen;
                    greenAvg += image[pl][pw].rgbtBlue;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Set the pixel - assuming no pixel value in original image > 255
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = redAvg / count;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = greenAvg / count;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = blueAvg / count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `% 256` is redundant.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are probably correct - assuming none of the original values are greater than 255.

Comment: In that case the OP's `redAvg > 255` is arguably more relevant, and not produce a gross error. You get my UV though.

Comment: @WeatherVane I see your point. Will update.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, for the if statement that has been added, is it perhaps redAvg += image[pl][pw].rgbtRed; instead of redAvg += image[pw][pl].rgbtRed; since the length would come first or am I missing something?

Comment: @HectorDevelops You are correct. Will fix.

Comment: Thanks for your help, to the both of you. @WeatherVane

Comment: @JohnnyMopp.    thanks

Comment: Please "accept" this answer if you feel it was good for you.

Comment: I accept. @WeatherVane

Comment: What you can do (you might not be able to immediately), is to find the green check mark and click it. That means you "accept" the answer and Johnny gets some points for the effort.

Comment: @HectorDevelops FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp, was able to do it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, I have some other questions.

Comment: or even @WeatherVane

Comment: Please ask a new question. One per question.

Comment: I will have to create another post and tag you both to receive some feedback, if possible.

Comment: Is it some detail about this question?

Comment: @WeatherVane I have updated the code file as well as image.

Comment: No, don't do that please, now the question has been answered. I just wondered if there was a small detail that could be answered.